# How to resolve MISRA C:2012 Rule 11.6?

Tags: c, embedded, misra

I am utilizing Microchip sample nvmem.c file function to write data into particular memory address of PIC32 Microcontroller. When I am trying to use it showing following MISRA error: I just posted sample code where I got an error. My whole code is compiled and working fine.

> 1] explicit cast from 'unsigned int' to 'void *' [MISRA 2012 Rule 11.6, required]  at  NVMemWriteWord((void*)APP_FLASH_MARK_ADDRESS,(UINT)_usermark);

How can I resolve this error?

```
nvmem.c
uint8_t NVMemWriteWord(void* address, uint32_t data)
{
    uint8_t res;
    NVMADDR = KVA_TO_PA((uint32_t)address); //destination address to write
    NVMDATA = data;
    res = NVMemOperation(NVMOP_WORD_PGM);
}

test.c
#define ADDRESS 0x9D007FF0U;
NVMemWriteWord((void*)ADDRESS,(uint32_t)_usermark);
```

Comment: The explanation of the 11.x Rules includes comments that "this may be necessary when accessing hardware registers".  If this is a case, then a Deviation (s5.4) is appropriate - and a deliberate part of MISRA.

Comment: @Andrew ; I see no reason that a deviation is justified in this case.  Casting _to_ a `void*` is _never_ necessary.  Deviations should be used when it is not reasonable or possible to comply with a rule; that is not the case here, where compliance is _better code_.

Comment: I respectfully suggest that the pointer is indeed *uint32_t and is only being nixed to void as an attempt to bypass the Rule...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest:

```
#define ADDRESS (volatile uint32_t*)0x9D007FF0U
NVMemWriteWord( ADDRESS, _usermark) ;
```

Never cast to `void*` - the purpose of `void*` is that you can assign any other pointer type to it safely and without explicit cast.  The cast of `_usermark` may or may not be necessary, but unnecessary explicit casts should be avoided - they can suppress important compiler warnings.  You should approach type conversions in the following order of preference:

- Type agreement - exactly same types.
- Type compatibility - smaller type to larger type, same signedness.
- Type case - last resort (e.g. larger to smaller type, signedness mismatch, integer to/from pointer).

In this instance since  `NVMemWriteWord` simply casts `address` to an integer, then the use of `void*` may not be appropriate. If in other contexts you are actually using a pointer, then it may be valid.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
uint8_t NVMemWriteWord(unsigned int  address, uint32_t data)
{
    uint8_t res;
    NVMADDR = KVA_TO_PA(address);
    NVMDATA = data;
    res = NVMemOperation(NVMOP_WORD_PGM);
}
```

and

```
#define  ADDRESS  0x9D007FF0U

NVMemWriteWord(ADDRESS,(uint32_t)_usermark);
```

instead.  Functionally it is exactly equivalent to the example, it just avoids the cast from a void pointer to an unsigned integer address.

Comment: thanks appreciate it. I edited question and added one more error .@Nominal

Comment: @raj123 Avoid changing the question once answers arrive.  It makes for an unclear  moving target.  Question rolled back.

Comment: @raj: One problem and one question at a time, like chux said.  If you had implemented the change first, you'd have noticed it also takes care of the second problem.

Comment: @NominalAnimal  uint8_t NVMemWriteWord(unsigned int * address, uint32_t data)  I have to use unsigned int pointer right instead of void pointer .

Comment: @raj123: It does not need to be a pointer. `unsigned int address` will work.

Answer (score 1):

The whole of MISRA-C:2012 chapter 12 regarding pointer conversions is quite picky. And rightly so, since this is very dangerous territory.

11.6 is a sound rule that bans conversions from integers to `void*`. The rationale is to block alignment bugs. There aren't many reasons why you would want to do such conversions anyway.

Notably, there's also two rigid but advisory rules 11.4 which bans conversions from integers to pointers, and 11.5 which pretty much bans the use of `void*` entirely. It isn't possible to do hardware-related programming and follow 11.4, so that rule has to be ignored. But you have little reason to use `void*`.

In this specific cast you can get away by using `uint32_t` and avoiding pointers entirely.

In the general case of register access, you must do a conversion with `volatile`-qualified pointers: `(volatile uint32_t*)ADDRESS`, assuming that the MCU uses 32 bit registers.